# excel combine values in one row to a comma seperated string

Tags: string, excel

i was looking around for a solution to this problem but i couldn't find a solution that satisfied me.
So here's the thing:
in excel i have one row with an unspecified amount of values (can be 30, can be 40, no one knows). What i want is to combine all those values in one cell separated by commas (a string). 
how can i do that with iterations?
One more thing: if the field is empty, the loop has to end (at the end of the list of values)

heres some sample data:

```
ROW A:
----
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

Result:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for a VBA solution, right?

Comment: no not exactly. would be nice if i can do it with a formula

Comment: I don't think that you can do that with a formula without selecting each cell at a time. Might be easier to copy/paste in something like MS Word or notepad++ (or another editor with regex find/replace) do to it and transfer the data back to excel.

Comment: yeah, thats what im actually doing at the moment, i was hoping for a formula doing it for me. But garys students script looks good, i'll give it a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following User Defined Function (UDF):

```
Public Function conkittenate(rIn As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
    conkittenate = ""
    For Each r In rIn
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            If conkittenate = "" Then
                conkittenate = r.Text
            Else
                conkittenate = conkittenate & ", " & r.Text
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

In the worksheet, it could be used like:

=conkittenate(A1:H1)

or

=conkittenate(A1:A5)